# How to show the current statusline definition?

Tags: statusline, ruler

I want to see the current statusline definition/string as loaded by Vim. So, taking into account `:help statusline`, if it is the default, the output would be empty, but if `ruler` is set (and nothing more) the output would be:

```
%<%f\ %h%m%r%=%-14.(%l,%c%V%)\ %P
```

I have tried `:echo statusline` but I get there is no such variable and I have tried `:echo $statusline`, but it does not appear any output.

Comment: Welcome to vi SE. Use `:set option?` or `:echo &option` to see the value of `option`.

Comment: @Friedrich I get something like `unknown option` in both cases

Comment: @iago you need to replace `option` by the actual `option-name`, e.g. in your case: `:echo &statusline`

Comment: Well, you would substitute `option` with the name of the option you're interested in. Try `:set statusline?`. You should at least see `statusline=` (and nothing more) if `statusline` is not set.

Comment: Thanks both! @Friedrich I see indeed `statusline=` with `:set statusline?`, however I have `set ruler` in my `.vimrc` and therefore I have a statusline.

Comment: The ruler is something different than the statusline however

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt ok, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help 'rulerformat'` and `:help 'statusline'` are both clear about this: their default value is empty. If the user doesn't set them explicitly (or implicitly, via some plugin), then some internal routine is used, which is not exposed to the user in any way and is unlikely to even look like `statusline` or `rulerformat`.

More generally, you can print the value of an option in the command-line with `:help :set`:

```
:set optionname?
```

or with `:help :echo`:

```
:echo &optionname
```

Note that these commands may have slightly different output.

In this case, both commands would do:

```
:set statusline?
:echo &statusline
```

You can also prepend `:help :verbose` to `:set`, which will tell you where the option was last set:

```
:verbose set statusline?
```